# can i do this? if( 2<a<8 , 1, 0) as Value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I know i can do this

`if( a<8 , 1, 0) as Value`

but can i do this?

`if( 2<a<8 , 1, 0) as Value` in mysql ?

I have tired, it doesn't work. if i want to get the 2nd result is there a way to do ?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work for me ... I mean if i want to get the 2nd result is there a way to do ?

Comment: it will work... BUT value will be 1 always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more standardized, I'd write this with a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN a > 2 AND a < 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can, but it doesn't give you the result you're hoping for. Perfectly valid, however.

Example:

```
SELECT IF(1 < 2 < 3, 1, 0) AS `value`
```

This returns '1'. It must work, right? Not really. What happens is the following:

```
Is 1 < 2 ? Sure! Let's return "1" (an INT because MySQL doesn't have a boolean TRUE)
Is 1 < 3 ? Sure!
```

So what happens when we do this?

```
SELECT IF(100 < 200 < 100) AS `value`
```

Well.. That's TRUE (1) as well. Because this happens:

```
Is 100 < 200? Sure! So let's return "1".
Is 1 < 100? Yep!
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but you can `IF( 2<a AND a<8, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF (a BETWEEN 3 AND 7, 1, 0) AS Value
```

Comment: BETWEEN includes the end points (`2<=a<=8`). The OP's example does not (`2<a<8`).

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could just use `SELECT a BETWEEN 3 AND 7` as this will return 1 or 0 anyway.

Using 3 and 7 because you want > 2 and < 8 not >= 2 and <= 8.

Your example will evaluate 2 < a which returns 0 or 1 depending on the value of `a`. Then it evaluates 0 < 8 or 1 < 8, which will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: Assuming that values in the column are integers.

Comment: Well that would be a reasonable assumption to make with no table schema available.